# How to use implicit localization with MVCSiteMap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to use implict localization with [MVCSiteMap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) but it's not working.

Here's my sample `Web.Sitemap`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-2.0" enableLocalization="true">

<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">

    <mvcSiteMapNode resourceKey="Products" title="Products" controller="Products" action="Index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" controller="Products" action="Edit" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Categories" controller="Categories" action="Index" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Suppliers" controller="Suppliers" action="Index" />

</mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

I have `resourceKey="Products"` in the above sitemap and a corresponding `Products.title` in `Web.sitemap.resx` file, inside `App_GlobalResources` folder. Followed these instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178427(VS.80).aspx

What I am missing here?

## Edit

This has been implemented in the [changeset 52831](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/workitem/5361).

Comment: Why down voted? Can someone explain it to me? What I asked wrong here?

Comment: +1 because this question does not deserve a down vote...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was addressed in the latest version (at the time of this writing, version 2.2.1) of MvcSitemapProvider thanks to the project's owner, Maarten Balliauw!

MvcSitemapProvider's implicit localization is almost identical as the default SitemapProvider ([see How to: Localize Site-Map Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178427.aspx)). The ONLY difference is that instead setting `<siteMap enableLocalization="true">` in the sitemap file itself, you must set this in the `Web.Config` file ([as described here](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Registering%20the%20provider&referringTitle=Home)).

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the title of the menu item from the resource file in your MvcSiteMapNode

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:MenuLocaliSations,Dashboard" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">
```

Comment: This is explicit localization, not what I want. I want to use the "resourceKey" attribute...